# A class augments the underlying data, but it should not

Tags: python, dataframe, class, oop

I have created a class that augments the underlying data, but is not meant to do so. Can you please explain where does this behaviour come from and how it can be prevented?

Here is the MWE: MyClass accepts a data frame to which I want to add a column of ones to the front and set the data as an attribute. This change is meant to occur only within the class.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, rhs):

        # Declare data
        self.rhs = MyClass._add_intercept(rhs)

    @staticmethod
    def _add_intercept(rhs):
        # Add ones to the front
        idxname = rhs.index.name
        rhs['A'] = 1
        rhs = rhs.reset_index().set_index('A').reset_index().set_index(idxname) 
        return rhs
```

When I create a data frame containing only zeros and pass it to the class and initiate the class,

```
rhs = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,2)), columns=['B','C'])
rhs.index.name = 'position'
instance = MyClass(rhs)
print(rhs)
```

the data frame now contains a column of ones, which should not be there.

```
     B    C  A
position             
0         0.0  0.0  1
1         0.0  0.0  1
2         0.0  0.0  1
3         0.0  0.0  1
```

So, what is behind this?

Comment: You need to make a copy of the dataframe, not modify it in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object passed to the class still points to the original dataframe. You should consider taking a copy of the dataframe, either before passing to the class, or within the `_add_intercept` method. For more information, see the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: For those looking for a deeper explanation, [this](https://archive.org/details/pyvideo_542___pyohio-2011-names-objects-and-plummeting-from-the-cliff) video helped me to understand the underlying logic (courtesy of @lukas-graf), whereas the answer by @TDeg solved the issue.